# Handling Custom Protocols

Tags: custom-protocol

I'm looking to respond to an event from a web browser, hopefully any web browser. I'm  working solely on windows and I came to the conclusion a custom protocol (I.E. `myprot://collection/of/strings`) is the best approach here (any objections?). But, handling an instance of this protocol seems to be a little less straight-forward. All I need is that collection of strings auto-magically passed to my already running application! (the app will only respond to these links while in a specific waiting state)

So answer me this, if you can, Whats the 'popular' method of handling them or better yet Whats the 'best' (subjective - I know) way to do it?

Although your answers don't need to be specific to my language, I am using Delphi for development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the regular urls? http://localhost/myhandler/collection/of/strings. To the best of my knowledge custom protocols only work for IE and you still need to install the handler on the client computer.

In the past I used custom protocols in one of my projects to support laptops working offline, but it was back in the time when installing IIS on a laptop was a call for trouble. but now - what's the point?

Comment: Running IIS, Tomcat or any other external server is crazy talk, at least for my purposes. Again, this functionality is only needed during one operation where the user would have to use a web browser to enter data (this is a requirement, not optional).

FYI the only modern browser I've come across that doesn't support custom protocols is chrome, and there is a workaround.

MSDN article on setting up these protocols: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx